# How to set max height for Tabulator table?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am trying to draw a table using

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: "75vh",
});
```

But, the height is always `75vh` even though contents are less which looks ugly. See the dark gray area below the table.
[image]

I tried using the below so that height is never above a value & resizes automatically if less content is there.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: "auto",
    maxHeight: "75vh",
});
```

Suggest me some hack as I coudn't get anthing in documentation.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185276/840992

Comment: @NoGrabbing That answer is for a very old version of Tabulator which relied on jQuery. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 4.6 there is now a ***maxHeight*** setup option:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    maxHeight:"100%", //do not let table get bigger than the height of its parent element
});
```